# Not to ask for permission for notifications in iOS but add "notification permission settings" into device settings?

Tags: ios, permissions, notifications, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I don't want to show "ask permission for notifications" dialog and just add disabled settings for my application into device settings.

The problem is if the application doesn't request these permissions then the relevant settings doesn't appear in device settings at all.

My code to call permission dialog:

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;
UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

Could you help to solve this issue? Currently I use local notifications only

Comment: You need to request notification permission for the section to be in settings

Comment: You don't have any choice in the matter, you must show the popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `Apple` documentation, you must ask for user permission first time. So in order to have settings you will have to ask user  atleast once.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks, I hoped I could create disabled settings without this dialog. For example when you add settings for your application inside the device settings - you just create them without of additional dialogs.

Answer (score -1):

I used it with my apps to receive Push Notification:-

```
// Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

Comment: Man `registerUserNotificationSettings:` calls a dialog which asks for permissions. Currently my app doesn't have remote notifications but it seems `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` will work via the same way.

Comment: 1)it will not work because `UIUserNotificationTypeSound` is available since iOS 8.
2)`registerForRemoteNotifications` will call the notification permission dialog immediately but the question is about how to avoid this dialog